# problem webview xamarin enable dom and javascript

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am noob in Xamarin forms. I create webview and i want to add my website in my app but i have problem with my js.

in my console : [image: error console]

in my Xamarin Forms MainPage.xml.cs:

```
  public MainPage(string link)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

      
      
        loadVideo_wv.Source = link;
 
        // InitializeComponent();
    }
```

in my MainPage.xml

```
  <local:WebViewer VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Navigating="OnNavigating" Navigated="OnNavigated" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" x:Name="loadVideo_wv"/>
```

how i can identify webview Xamarin forms in my Xamarin android and Xamarin IOS to enable dom and javascript like that:

```
 settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: To modify the default behavior of WebView, you will need **custom renderers** for ios and android. See [Customizing a WebView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the code in android renderer for webview like:

```
public class Mywebview : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public Mywebview(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {

                Android.Webkit.WebView webview = (Android.Webkit.WebView)Control;
                WebSettings settings = webview.Settings;
                settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: i tried 2 days ... i had my new function "Mywebview" in my android project but does not work... It's possible to see all solution in Xamarin forms and Xamarin android please ? thanks

Comment: try this https://github.com/SKLn-Rad/Xam.Plugin.Webview

Comment: @Adrain I am having same problem though I enabled javascript from custom renderer it is not working